# "vector" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, vector

I got this error ,,"vector" was not declared in this scope'' for the following code when I separate in *h and *cpp a file
This is the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include "functia.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
 {
  vector<double> s(3);
  double b= 4;
  fun(s, b);
  cout<<s[0]<<endl;
  double c= 9;
  fun(s, c);
  cout<<s[0];

  }
```

functia.h:

```
 void fun(vector<double> & rS, double a)
 {
   rS[0] = a + 3;
   rS[1] = 4;
   rS[2] = 5;
 }
```

functia.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


void fun(vector<double> &, double );
```

Comment: Why does you _.cpp_ contain the declaration and you _.h_ file the definition of `fun(...)`? Something seems odd there.

Comment: i already tried, it is not working

Comment: This is how I learned: in .cpp the declaration and in .h the definition. It is working in that way for files without ,,vector''.

Comment: Lots of bugs in code, its not just vector error, solve other bugs vector won't be issue.

Comment: @MIhaela, As soon as two files include the same header, you violate the One Definition Rule.

Comment: _"This is how I learned: in .cpp the declaration and in .h the definition"_ That is backwards.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got the declaration in the cpp file and the definition in the header, it should really be the other way round.

After you've swapped the files round remove `using namespace std;` from functia.h as it's not good practice to pull in namespaces in header files. You'll need to change the declaration to

`void fun(std::vector<double> &, double );`

See ["using namespace" in c++ headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849457/using-namespace-in-c-headers)

I'd also strongly recommend reading [C/C++ include file order/best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-file-order-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

Change "vector" to  "std::vector"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34371992)