# std::ostream recognize without defining header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files, iostream

I created this code:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Quote.h"

int main()
{
    derived().print(std::cout);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Quote.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class base {
public:
    std::string name() { return basename; }
    virtual void print(std::ostream &os) { os << basename; }

private:
    std::string basename = "abc";
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    void print(std::ostream &os) { base::print(os); os << " " << i; }

private:
    int i = 0;
};
```

If I don't include the *iostream* header file in *Main.cpp*, as expected, **std::cout** is not recognized. My question is: Why there's no problem with the use of **std::ostream** in *Quote.h* if *iostream* is not included?. Either **cout** as **ostream** are defined in the aforementioned library, why the **cout** use is a problem and **ostream** not?

I'm using **VS 2017**, in case this info is important.

Comment: There is no rule that prevents one of the standard headers from including another so sometimes this will happen depending on implementation.

Comment: `<string>` probably includes `<iostream>` or `<iosfwd>`, or vice versa.  - but you should never depend on this; always explicitly include all the headers who's definitions you need.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I’d hope it does _not_ include `<iostream>`: it doesn’t need anything specific to that header! The stream definitions can be obtained from `<istream>` and `<ostream>`.

Comment: @Dietmar Well, of course I hope so too. But it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All existing answers concentrate on `#include <string>`. I'd like to point at another side. Consider slightly modified version:

`quote.h`:

```
#pragma once

// uncomment to get an analog of original example
// #include <string>

struct Quote {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Quote const&)
{
    return os << "quote\n";
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "quote.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << Quote{};
}
```

As you see `#include <string>` is commented out, `quote.h` still doesn't include `iostream` and the program still compiles. It does because only source files (.cpp, or translation units) are directly compiled. Headers are literally included. Now if we literally include `quote.h` in `main.cpp` we get:

```
#include <iostream>

// uncomment to get an analog of original example
// #include <string>

struct Quote {};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Quote const&)
{
    return os << "quote\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Quote{};
}
```

([online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0yCBVrHQ8Z4EB2nB))

It's what actually gets compiled. Notice everything is alright here, `#include <iostream>` before `std::ostream` usage.

And as was correctly pointed in comment to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51912913/453271), this is an example why it's important to always maintain self-sufficient headers that include all headers they depend on.

As @Evgeny pointed out in the comment, please check [recommendations about organising our includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-file-order-best-practices).

Comment: Please mention in your answer what would happen if the order of includes is changed: `#include <iostream> // #include "Quote.h"` to `#include "Quote.h" // #include <iostream>`. This is the reason why STL headers should be at the end of `#include` list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-file-order-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

The header `<string>` declares an output operator using `std::ostream`. It seems the implementation you are using does so in a way making `std::ostream` generally available.

The C++ standard defines which headers make which declarations available at least. It doesn’t prohibit against additional names being made available. Different implementations may choose to not make the declarations available. I have tried making strictly only mandated declarations available in my implementation but this turns out to be not quite as simple as it sounds.

Answer (score 2):

You include `<string>` in your header file. If you go to the `string` header you will see the first lines as (in VS2017):

```
// string standard header
#pragma once
#ifndef _STRING_
#define _STRING_
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
#include <istream> <----- here
#include <xstring_insert.h>
```

and going to the `istream` header:

```
// istream standard header
#pragma once
#ifndef _ISTREAM_
#define _ISTREAM_
#ifndef RC_INVOKED
#include <ostream> <-- here
```

which I think already answers your question. However, this is implementation dependent and you should not rely on this but include explicitly the `iostream` header.

Answer (score 1):

The header `<string>` provides [the extraction and insertion operators for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt), so it has to make sure that `std::ostream` is at least forward-declared; your code only uses a reference to `ostream`, for which a forward declaration suffices, plus the aforementioned insertion operator, which is correctly declared.

So, strictly speaking, all that is needed by your header is already provided by the header `<string>`, although I'd probably explicitly include `<iosfwd>` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

> Why there's no problem with the use of `std::ostream` in Quote.h if `<iostream>` is not included?

`<iostream>` get `#include`d indirectly.

It's best not to rely on such indirection `#include`s. You can't count on it being true on all platforms. It may even change from debug build to release build.

When you want to use a class or a function, it's best to lookup the standard for the header that's supposed to provide the definition of the class and the declaration of the function, and `#include` the header directly in your file.

Comment: Even if we remove `#include <string>` the program still compiles fine. Please see my answer. Am I right that it's an important part of a complete answer?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko, your answer provides another important reason why not `#include`ing a required header file in another header file can be a hidden problem. Ideally, header files should be self-sufficient. If you can't compile a .cc file that has one line, `#include "quote.h"`, then the header file is not self-sufficient.