# Including the corresponding header first. What problems does it NOT solve?

Tags: c++, templates, include, precompiled-headers, name-lookup

There is a similar rule in most style guides:

> Include the .hpp in the corresponding .cpp
> as the first substantive line of code.
> Even if the .cpp is otherwise empty.

The latter sentence is popularized by John Lakos. See e.g. CppCon 2016: John Lakos “Advanced Levelization Techniques (part 1 of 3)", at 7:28:

[image]

This rule ensures, that our headers are self-contained, i.e. they compile in isolation, or in other words they don't require other headers in front of them to compile.

But, does this ensure, that we will *never* have include order dependencies?

Comment: *"What problems does it NOT solve?"* ¿Question implies that it actually solves some problems? ¿Which problems? It is not clear why would you assume that it will somehow prevent include order dependencies from occurring.

Comment: _"Does this ensure that we will never have include order dependencies ?"_ Yes, for that header and anything upstream. But for what you do downstream, it's outside the header's scope (e.g. if you build something that have dependencies order issues and you happen to use that header in the given dependencies)

Comment: d'oh. too little coffe perhaps :P

Comment: @user7860670: There is a question exactly about this: [Why include the corresponding header first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52716773/why-include-the-corresponding-header-first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ensures in *most cases* that we will not have include order dependencies, and does not ensure it in at least the following cases.

#### 1. Ordinary lookup of dependent names

There are three different roles in this story.

1. Alfred is a library developer. He writes the FooBarBaz lib.
2. Bob writes an `N::MyClass` class, which is intended to be used with FooBarBaz lib.
3. Goofy is an innocent character, he just wants to use `N::MyClass` with FooBarBaz, but runs into problems.

###### Alfred

Alfred plays first. FooBarBaz, this magnificent library has some functions which operate on client types, which are accepted as template parameters. The client's types are supposed to have a function named `FBBSize()` which

- accepts the client's type as parameter,
- returns `int`, and
- is declared in the same file and namespace as the client's type. Alfred wants to find `FBBSize()` with ADL.

The library calls `FBBSize()` in its function templates, and it even has a concept `SupportsFBBSize` which tells if a type has a corresponding `FBBSize()` function. Alfred's header-only library `FBB.hpp` might look something like this:

```
// --- FBB.hpp ---
namespace FBB {
    template <class T>
    concept SupportsFBBSize = requires(const T& value) { FBBSize(value); };

    template <class T>
    void SomeFunction(const T& value) {
        FBBSize(value);
    }
}
```

###### Bob

Then, Bob writes a class `MyClass` in namespace `N` and wants to support its usage with the FooBarBaz lib. Thus, he declares an `FBBSize()` function in the header, but erroneously he puts the function into the global namespace. His `MyClass.hpp` looks like this:

```
// --- MyClass.hpp ---
namespace N {
    class MyClass {};
}
inline int FBBSize(const N::MyClass&) { return 123; }
```

###### Goofy

Now, both headers compile in isolation, but if Goofy wants to use `FBB::SomeFunction()` with `N::MyClass`, only this include order will compile:

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "FBB.hpp"

int main() {
    N::MyClass mc;
    FBB::SomeFunction(mc);
}
```

If you swap the `#include` directives, you get a compilation error.

The reason is arcane. In `SomeFunction()` `FBBSize()` is an unqualified dependent name, which is looked up using

- ordinary lookup in the template definition context, and
- argument-dependent lookup in the instantiation context.

In the order as above, `FBBSize()` is found using ordinary lookup (contrary to Alfred's intention) in the context of the definition of `SomeFunction()`, i.e. "above" `SomeFunction()`. ADL finds nothing, because `FBBSize()` isn't in namespace `N`. However, if you swap the `#include` directives, `FBBSize()` will be declared "below" `SomeFunction()`, so neither lookup will find it, and compilation will fail.

It's even harder to notice the bug, if instead calling `FBB::SomeFunction()` Goofy uses the concept `FBB::SupportsFBBSize`. The `main()` function will compile in both include orders, however, the value of the concept will depend on the order:

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "FBB.hpp"

int main() {
    return FBB::SupportsFBBSize<N::MyClass>;
}
```

The above `main()` function returns `true`, but if you swap the `#include` directives, it will return `false`.

###### Solution

Goofy would have got the same result, i.e. the same compilation errors, and the same value for the concept, in both orders of the `#include` directives,

- if in `MyClass.hpp` Bob would have put `FBBSize()` into namespace `N`, or
- if in `FBB.hpp` Alfred would have somehow "disabled" ordinary lookup of `FBBSize()`.

The problem with ordinary lookup is not that it's ordinary, but that it's executed in the template definition context. If `FBBSize()` is to be found "above" the template definition, `FBB.hpp` will require the header of the client's class in front of it to work as intended.

This is not an actual, but a potential include order dependency. We could say, `FBB.hpp` has the potential in it, to depend on the header of the client's class.

To eliminate that potential, Alfred has to stop ordinary lookup of `FBBSize()` at the scope of namespace `FBB`. He could put a dummy declaration of an `FBBSize()` function in namespace `FBB` before all facilities of the header:

```
// --- FBB.hpp ---
namespace FBB {
    int FBBSize(...) = delete;      // declare FBBSize() in the same file and namespace as your type

    template <class T>
    concept SupportsFBBSize = requires(const T& value) { FBBSize(value); };

    template <class T>
    void SomeFunction(const T& value) {
        FBBSize(value);
    }
}
```

The dummy declaration has to be a function. If it would be a variable or a type, ADL would not be executed.

Now, when Goofy tries to compile his 1<sup>st</sup> example (which uses `FBB::SomeFunction()`), it won't compile in any include order, because ADL finds nothing. It will always work the same way in both include orders, because `FBBSize()` can only be found in the instantiation context.

The comment after the dummy declaration is a reminder for the clients. The compiler will show it in the error message when it cites that line from the code. It's a workaround until you cannot use `= delete("custom error message")`, see [EWG152](https://wg21.link/ewg152).

Goofy's 2<sup>nd</sup> example (which uses `FBB::SupportsFBBSize`) will also work the same way in both include orders. The value of the concept will be `false` in both cases.

You can play with the above code snippets on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1YMP3hnfs).

#### 2. Qualified lookup of dependent names

Recall that the problem with ordinary lookup is not that it's ordinary, but that it's executed in the template definition context. Qualified lookup is also executed in the template definition context, and introduces the same potential include order dependency.

I mention this example for the sake of completeness, but I don't think, that it's a real life problem.

- It requires the client to define a function in the library's namespace, which I consider a bad idea.
- There is no solution. The potential include order dependency cannot be eliminated.

There are the same three actors in this play.

1. Alfred writes the FooBarBaz lib.
2. Bob writes an `N::MyClass` class, which is intended to be used with FooBarBaz lib.
3. Goofy just wants to use `N::MyClass` with FooBarBaz, but runs into problems.

###### Alfred

This time Alfred wants the client types to have a `Size()` function, which

- accepts the client type as parameter,
- returns `int`, and
- is declared in the same file as the client type, but in the library's namespace (`FBB`).

Alfred's header:

```
// --- FBB.hpp ---
namespace FBB {
    template <class T>
    requires requires { T::Size; }
    int Size(const T&) {
        return T::Size;
    }

    template <class T>
    concept SupportsFBBSize = requires(const T& value) { FBB::Size(value); };

    template <class T>
    void SomeFunction(const T& value) {
        FBB::Size(value);
    }
}
```

He implemented a "default" `Size()` function. This way the client can put a public `Size` constant in his class instead of declaring a `Size()` function. Another reason for having this function in front of every call to it, is that without it `FBB.hpp` won't compile in isolation. Compilers would notice, that there is no `Size` in namespace `FBB`, therefore they can prove, that no specialization of these templates compile, and report the error early.

###### Bob

Bob does everything according to FooBarBaz's documentation:

```
// --- MyClass.hpp ---
namespace N {
    class MyClass {};
}
namespace FBB {
    inline int Size(const N::MyClass&) { return 123; }
}
```

This header also compiles in isolation.

###### Goofy

Goofy wants to use `FBB::SomeFunction()` and `FBB::SupportsFBBSize` with `N::MyClass`:

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "FBB.hpp"

int main() {
    N::MyClass mc;
    FBB::SomeFunction(mc);
}
```

```
#include "MyClass.hpp"
#include "FBB.hpp"

int main() {
    return FBB::SupportsFBBSize<N::MyClass>;
}
```

The 1<sup>st</sup> example compiles, and in the 2<sup>nd</sup> the `main()` function returns `true`. However, if you swap the `#include` directives, the 1<sup>st</sup> won't compile, and the 2<sup>nd</sup> will return `false`.

###### Solution

There is no solution for this potential include order dependency.

You can play with the above code snippets on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/hbE99b7jh).

#### 3. Precompiled headers

Suppose, you work for a company, where for every DLL there is a dedicated precompiled header. Therefore, these headers can differ.

As a consequence by following the style guide rule you can verify that your header compiles in isolation, but that verification will be only valid in the DLL of the header, and not in the entire code base.

Suppose you write a class `Monkey` in `Zoo.dll`, which uses class `X`. You forget to include `X.hpp`, but suppose `X.hpp` is in `Zoo.dll`'s precompiled header:

```
// --- Monkey.hpp ---
class Monkey {
    X x;
};
```

`Monkey.cpp` includes `Monkey.hpp` as the first substantive line of code. It compiles all right, because when it compiles, `Zoo.dll`'s precompiled header (and `X.hpp` in it) will be silently included in front of the entire translation unit.

If however, someone else wants to use this header in another DLL, where `X.hpp` is not included in the precompiled header, they will get a compilation error.

###### Solution

Two approaches come to mind.

1. The build system should compile all headers in isolation and without precompiled headers. Preprocessing and semantic analysis is enough. The goal is to ensure, that `#include "X.hpp"` is not forgotten.
2. The build system should ensure, that if `B.dll` depends on `A.dll` then `B.pch.hpp` includes `A.pch.hpp`.

#### Library headers and Include What You Use is a different topic

This is a related problem, but not our topic. I mention it only because people seemingly think, that it belongs here.

The common example is the C++ Standard Library, where you use a facility, but you don't include the proper header. Consider the following `Fun.hpp`:

```
#include <type_traits>

std::int64_t Fun();
```

The type `std::int64_t` is defined in `cstdint`. In MSVC `type_traits` includes `cstdint` (see on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/5897d9820619a72b242292ceb5fbf1f829404655/stl/inc/type_traits#L11)), therefore, `Fun.cpp` (which includes `Fun.hpp` in its first line) compiles. But it doesn't compile with Clang and GCC. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d69z3981K).

This is similar to an include order dependency. One could say, `Fun.hpp` requires `cstdint` in front of it. But, in our topic we are talking about a fixed compiler, and about files under our control.

- In case of MSVC `Fun.hpp` is self-contained.
- In case of Clang and GCC it is not, but `Fun.cpp` won't compile.

Similarly, we could think about updating a 3<sup>rd</sup> party library to the latest version, and contrive similar examples. We could think about integrating code from other source branches. Finally, we could ask, what if MSVC won't include `cstdint` in `type_traits` in the future? All these problems are related, but different problems, and the solution to them is [Include What You Use](https://github.com/include-what-you-use/include-what-you-use?tab=readme-ov-file#instructions-for-users).

In the above `Fun.hpp` we run into compilation errors when porting from MSVC to a different compiler, but that's not because `Foo.hpp` is not self-contained, but because we didn't include precisely what we use. We included the definition of `std::int64_t` indirectly.