# System headers before other headers according to Google Style guide?

Tags: c++, header, google-style-guide, cpplint

I was playing with `cpplint` and I got this warning:

```
Found C++ system header after other header. Should be: transpose_square.h, c system, c++ system, other.
```

The source is the Google Styleguide, that apparently says ([said?](https://www.ostricher.com/2014/11/sort-your-include-files/))

```
1. associated .h/.hpp (if this is a .cpp file)
2. C system files
3. C++ system files
4. Other libraries' .h/.hpp files
5. Your project’s .h/.hpp files
```

Leaving aside `1.`, I honestly thought that the recommended order was exactly the opposite!

```
2. Your project’s .h/.hpp files
3. Other libraries' .h/.hpp files
4. C++ system files
5. C system files
```

So, basically the idea is to include the headers in the order of "increasing distance" from the current project, ending with the most basic libraries.

I don't remember where I took that from, but I remember the logic was to detect missing dependencies headers in related or in the same project.

I don't remember if there was more than just this.

For example, in this case, the order will be forgiving for `text_processing_utilities.hpp` to have a missing `#include<string>` even if it depends on it:

```
#include<string>
#include "text_processing_utilities.hpp"
```

My question is, is the Google Style guide for headers a good convention regarding the order of system headers? Is there a good reason for it?

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762568/c-c-include-header-file-order/14243688#14243688

Comment: Who ever said the google style guide was good. I have never seen a good argument for it! Personally I use the order you suggest. My reasoning is that this way will expose missing headers that are required for that header file to stand alone. The way I express it is: Order headers from Most specific to Most general (relative to your project).  C system files being the most generic functionality you can get that everybody else depends on.

Comment: You're right, I thought that was stupid, after all, it's just a "style", do what you want as long as it is comfortable for you, and the others.

Comment: In the help is stated that cpplint has other options, such as `build/include_alpha` which I see used as `filter=-build/include_order,+build/include_alpha,+build/include_subdir`. But it is not clear what they mean.